# Find the remainder of $101st$ term of a sequence modulus $102$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Consider the sequence: $a_{n+1}=(n+1)a_n+n , a_0=0$. Calculate the remainder of $a_{101}$ modulus $102$

Firstly I calculated some terms of the sequence: $a_1=0,a_2=1,a_3=5,a_4=23$
$a_{101}=101a_{100}+100\equiv{100-a_{100}}\pmod{102}$
But nothing more. I think we should find a general closed formula for $a_n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Try to prove $a_n=n!-1$ by induction.

Comment: How could you find that formula? Just by guess??!!!

Comment: No... In fact, divide by $(n+1)!$ both side of your formula, to get a "telescopic" formula, and use $\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{(k+1)!}$.

Comment: Thank you,that's simple.Now $a_{101}=101!-1\equiv 101 \pmod{102}$

Comment: You don't even really need to prove it by induction. You can just plug it into the recurrence relation and verify it's a solution. Then by existence and uniqueness, it is the only non trivial solution.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a_m\equiv -1\bmod n$, then $a_{m+1}\equiv (m+1)\times-1+m\equiv-1\bmod n$.

Now notice $a_m=m(a_{m-1}+(m-1)\equiv -1\bmod m$.

So if $m\leq n$ then $a_n\equiv -1 \bmod m$.

Therefore $a_{101}\equiv -1 \bmod 2,3,17\implies a_{101}\equiv -1 \bmod 102$